# Volume of a hypersurface in flat families?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose that $X_t$ is the vanishing of $x^2 + y^2 + t z^2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. For $t \not = 0$, this is a submanifold, and it inherits a Riemannian metric from the Fubini-Studi metric on $\mathbb{CP}^2$. So one can compute its volume. Similarly, for $t = 0$, it is a.e. a manifold, and one can also compute its volume.

Question: Is the surface area of $X_0$ equal to the surface area of $X_1$? Note in particular that all of the $X_t$, for $t \not = 0$, are projectively equivalent, so if the surface area was an invariant that was stable (or at least varied smoothly) in families like this, then the answer is yes. (To keep the habit of citing my sources fairly, even if both of us are anonymous people from your point of view, I posed the secret question below to a friend and she suggested looking at this family. Neither of us are complex geometers though, so we couldn't tell if this would work.)

(Secret question: I really want to know if the volume of a degree d curve is d times the volume of a linear hypersurface.)

Apologies in advance if this question is very naive - pretty much everything I know about the Fubini-Studi metric I learned from wikipedia.

Comment: The volume is equal to the degree.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Neat, that is I guess what I expected... I want to make the same kind of argument as in my question, but I don't know if the method will work in general. A degree $d$ curve is can be degenerated to some monomial, which will be an (a.e) disjoint union of $Z(x_i^{n_i})$. Will the "volume" of $Z(x^n)$ be $n$, in some reasonable sense that is preserved in these degenerations? (It is kind of funny to think of a non-reduced curve as having extra volume, but I guess that makes sense. I don't really know what non-formal notion of volume would encompass that, though.)